# How to combine pixels from every frames of a video (Python and OpenCV)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

The code below allows me to read the arrays of each frame of a video.

What should I do to find the mean-value of the individual pixels and formulate a new picture from the result?

Much thanks!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# loading the video
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testing.mp4')
success, img = vidcap.read()

# establish a while loop for reading all the video frames
frames = 0

while success:

    success, image = vidcap.read()
    copimg = img[65:230, 0:350]
    blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(copimg, (5, 5), 3)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(blur_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        

    frames += 1
    print gray_img
```

Comment: Do you mean the mean-value of RGB elements for each pixel?

Comment: Actually, I will convert the image to grayscale by using cv2.cvtColor(blur_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).

So, it should be the mean-value of each element of the grayscale array.

Comment: probably you should try to do the online mean or running mean for each pixel.... at the end of the video you will have the mean of each pixel... to can add them together and then divide it but this will be more inaccurate if the video is too big

Comment: @api55 The video to be run only takes up 8 seconds. Now I can print out arrays of each frames separately(about 293 frames), but I wasn’t able to join them together inside the while loop.

Comment: well you need to create a mat the same size outside the for loop, like with numpy zeros function. Then just use numpy.add or opencv's add and then divide all the numbers with number of frames... remember to use something that may contain large numbers like double or something like that

Comment: @api55 I've tired to create an empty array of the same size as you mentioned and perform np.add();  However, it kept showing the mean of the empty array and the pixel array of the first frame, instead of all the frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comments it depends on how long the video may be, but you may do the naive way and add all to an accumulator and divide... I say naive way, since this method may carry inaccuracies...  the ideal one would be to do a online mean of it (at the cost of performance perhaps)... ([here is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) pseudo code for online mean)...

For the naive case, create an accumulator and add all frames (or the piece you want). Your code has a mistake and you do not work on the new frame but only on the first one. Here is the code with this problem fix.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# loading the video
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testing.mp4')
success, img = vidcap.read()

# establish a while loop for reading all the video frames
frames = 0
# accumulator in double precision
avg = np.zeros((165,350), dtype=np.float64)
while success:

    success, img = vidcap.read()
    copimg = img[65:230, 0:350]
    blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(copimg, (5, 5), 3)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(blur_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    avg = np.add(avg, gray_img)

    frames += 1

avg = np.divide(avg, frames)
print (avg)
```

I hope this helps you, otherwise leave a comment

Comment: This works nice! Thank you fro your help on this. 

Adding on this, how should I find the standard deviation of each pixel? Can the same logic be applied?

Comment: @K.CHAN actually the link for the online mean also tells you how to calculate the variance (std_dev^2). So basically you will need to implement the pseudocode... the good thing is that it is not complicated, just use numpy functions to do it to the image

Comment: I think the method of calculating first the variance works perfectly. Thanks for your advice!